# Will Google Analytics automatically convert breadcrumbs when running an experiment?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, structured-data, breadcrumbs

I want to run an experiment to try out alternative pages using Google Analytics experiments. What I want to know though is will my breadcrumbs be handled by Google or will I have to update them automatically?

e.g. on my home page it displays the breadcrumb `You Are Here: Home`
on my experiment page will it think it is the home page, or will I have to manually configure this. For info this is an asp.net webforms site with the breadcrumb control bound to the web.sitemap file

Comment: I have seen some of Google employee said in their product forums, "do not include breadcrumbs in your homepage, it does not make any sense. "

Comment: @Goyllo - maybe but this is just an example. The experiment could easily be on a different page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run an experiment, Google Analytics doesn't handle anything other than deciding which version your visitors see, and tracking your visitors.   You need to implement all changes to the page (including breadcrumbs) yourself.

You usually do so by creating a copy of the page you want to experiment with and change only the parts of it that need to be tested.  If you make a copy of the home page and want to experiment with it, you would generally NOT change the breadcrumbs.  The copy of the page would take the place of your homepage for visitors that are part of the experiment.    The JavaScript snippet that has to be included in both the original and copy pages should prevent any particular user from seeing both versions. Only the URL and the experimental items should be different.